# Seaborn point plot using dates as x-axis

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am trying to produce a point plot of dataset grouped based on the date of data collection using Seaborn.

After playing with Seaborn point plot a little while, I realized an issue: these data were collected on different dates but the dates are not evenly spaced. It seems to me that during plotting, Seaborn was considering the dates as categorical variables.

[image: image produced]

I am wondering if there is a way for me to locate the data with spacing corresponding to the dates interval?

Comment: If you want help, you'll have more success by providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I disagree to what @Evert says. Seaborn pointplot is a categorical plot and categories are evenly spaced on the pointplot no matter their datatype. That said, I don't think pointplot is actually what you're looking for here, but rather a scatter plot. In order to help you produce the desired plot, one would want to have some sample data in the question.

Comment: @Evert the x-values are 'datetime' objects already, but the pointplot in Seaborn doesn't seem to space them accordingly.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thanks a lot. You are absolutely right. I used the error_bar plot in matplotlib and solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I guess you shouldn't answer your own question within the question. If you think that what you found out is useful for others, write it down as answer to your question. You can then accept your own answer (after 2 days) such that the question is marked as solved. Mind that the function in matplotlib is called `errorbar`, not `error_bar`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that Seaborn doesn't support `datetime` as the x variables, and all the dates are considered as categorical variables in this case. It might not be a big issue here but it prevents me from fitting a regression line to the dots.

I ended up using the `matplotlib.errorbar` function, with the median value and std calculated using `numpy`. It doesn't seem to be an ideal solution but it worked. (Still working on the regression trendline but I'm fine now.)

[updated plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3RlJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to convert your string dates into `datetime` objects

```
import time
import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime

def dateconvert(Start_date):
    try:
        Start_date = int(Start_date)  
        Date_String = str(Start_date)
        dateconv = dt.datetime.strptime(Date_String,'%YYYY-%mm-%dd').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        return  dateconv
    except ValueError:
        return Start_date #or '' or whatever you want to return for NULL
```

Comment: Taylrl, thanks for your answer. However, the data are already in datetime objects, the problem is that Seaborn failed to plot them to scale.